How do i use Angular CLI inside a dockerized app?
Is there a way to use CLI commands when developing on dockerized instances i connect remotely to?
I work with a monolith and connect to the codebase remotely, where i run docker instances for our frontends.
Right now Imade a local build with newest angular, because we intend to upgrade incrementally and we want to introduce this version and develop new features on it as well as migrate old features on it over time.
I want to use Angular CLI to generate the boilerplate for the new components, but I am not sure how to use it in this setup, builds networks and backend are not my strengths.
This is how i setup
[ Dockerfile ]
FROM node:18.20-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
RUN npm install

COPY . .
EXPOSE 4200 49153

CMD npm run start
CMD ['ng']

[ compose.yaml ]
services:
  docker-beta-3:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
      - 49153:49153
    volumes:
      - "/app/node_modules"
      - ".:/app"

I've tried using this to access the shell and run my "ng generate component comp1" there, but it doesn't recognize the "ng"
I can run the command when being in the right folder, but that's just what I have installed locally and I get that
docker exec -it 0bd974419cae sh


Can you check out the source code locally and develop against it using normal tools, without specifically needing either the remote system or Docker?  If you have a working local Node application then you should be able to wrap it in a boilerplate Dockerfile like you've shown.  (Make sure to delete the Compose volumes: block, and only the last Dockerfile CMD has an effect.)

Sorry if I expressed myself badly, but this is just local wrapped in a docker. The end goal is to have it running on the remote, but as of right now it only passed running normally local as well as running into a docker.
Now i'm trying to prepare for using the CLI on the remote docker in the future, which is why i'm trying to understand how the CLI relates to a docker instance and how to make it work.
Why are you suggesting deleting the volumes lines?

The normal way to deploy something in Docker is to docker build an image, docker push it to a registry, and then docker run it on the remote system.  You would not normally copy the source code around, so it won't exist on the remote system.  These volumes: hide everything in your image, so you're deploying an untested image.  I wouldn't bother trying to "develop in Docker"; just install Node locally and use that.

It doesn't recognize the command [ng], not ng, you're using ['ng'] instead of ["ng"]
Also, your previous CMD line is ignored, only one (the last written) is used
